# Create Folder on SharePoint using VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2010, sharepoint-online

I have this code on the OnClick_Event of a button on a form to Create a folder on my pc.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim fs, cf, strFolder
Dim FolderName As String

FolderName = DLookup("F_SNr", "tblFahrzeug", "F_SNr = '" & Me.F_SNr.Value & "'")

strFolder = "C:\Users\IQeov95\Desktop\All Data\" & FolderName & ""
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fs.FolderExists(strFolder) = True Then
    MsgBox "'" & strFolder & "' already exists!"
Else
   Set cf = fs.CreateFolder(strFolder)
       If fs.FolderExists(strFolder) = True Then
          MsgBox "'" & strFolder & "' successfully created!"
       Else
          MsgBox "'" & strFolder & "' was not created successfully!"
       End If
End If
```

The code works just fine as long as the path is on my pc. How does the "strFolder" variable has to look like to create the folder on my SharePoint? I've tryed entering the SharePoint link but that didnt work. Also i tryed using the MkDir command but got the Run Time Error 76: Path not found.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the Sharepoint via Windows Explorer? For me, it's working if I just use the path Windows Explorer shows when I navigate into the directory. The online link won't work like this.

Comment: Unfortunately I used the online link. Not sure how to check the access via the explorer. What should i type in?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b).

Comment: Thanks a lot GWD i found the SharePoint integration on the Windows Explorer and it works perfectly using the folder path, just like you said!